# How to fix incorrect syntax near '@P1'

Tags: php, sql, authentication, sql-server-2008

My login procedure in SQL Server generates an error.

Here is my code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["utilizador"] = $_POST['utilizador'] ?? null;
$_SESSION["password"] = $_POST['password'] ?? null;
// login action
    if (isset($_SESSION["utilizador"]) && isset($_SESSION["password"])){    
        $utilizador = $_SESSION['utilizador']; // set variable
        $password = $_SESSION['password']; // set variable
        
        require 'ligacao_bd.php'; // connect database
        $pdo = Conexao::getConnection();
        $sql = "EXEC sp_login(?, ?)"; 
        $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(1, $utilizador, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->bindParam(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statement->execute();
        $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        if ($resultado) { // if there is a result go to 
            header("location: utilizadores.php" );
        }else{
            echo "NO PERMISSIONS";
        }
    }
```

When I execute it generates the error:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'." supposedly in line "*$statement->execute();*

Comment: `EXEC sp_login(?, ?)` Parameters for procedures don't go in parenthesis.

Comment: Side note, SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for **3 years**; it is long past time you sorted out your upgrade path.

Comment: Are you storing the passwords in plain text (which would be _very_ bad), or are you using some hashing algorithm in the stored procedure? Also, why are you storing the data in a session before you even checked if the credentials are correct? And even if they are correct, you shouldn't store the password in the session. Once the user has verified the credentials, you shouldn't need to keep them around.

Comment: Also, I don't recognise `sp_login` as a system procedure; documented or undocumented. If `sp_login` is a **user** procedure, it is a poor choice of a name. The prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)